# Date field exposed filter - select year

Tags: 8, views, datetime

Back in Drupal 7 I've created exposed filter with Year from date field. (Selet list).

- View all
- 2017
- 2016
- 2015
  etc...

And when creating such filter we had options like on this picture:

[image]

BUT, now in Drupal 8 I cannot see that is supported.

I've installed Better Exposed filters but only thing is that I can select datepicker instead of plain text field for this filter, but I need select list and only years.

If it's not possible yet, where I can find examples of creating custom exposed filters or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Luckily just a day before your question this tutorial for year select filter was posted on Drupal planet:

https://www.flocondetoile.fr/blog/filter-content-year-views-drupal-8

Comment: Thanks, but actually it is posted 8 months after :)

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't look at the date, question was obviously bumped by bot :-)